# How to get dropdown selected value and assign to state in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, state

So I am having trouble getting the selected value from the dropdown button and assign in to my state.

This is my change function:

```
change = (e) => {
this.setState({
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
})};
```

My dropdown menu:

```
<Dropdown name="course" onChange={e => this.change(e)}>
            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="classes">
              Course
              </Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
              <Dropdown.Item>Math234</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item>Art101</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item>Something else</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
```

When user types something in the other fields  have, it does get assign to my other state value, it's just this one I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

If you just do `onChange={this.change}` and console.log e.target.value in change method what do you get? You shouldn't have to pass e in an anonymous function since e is the first argument passed by an event by default. Im new to React but normal js events work that way